# Does it make a copy before adding Strings into a Collection?

Tags: java

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String string = null;
string = "123";
list.add(string);
string = "456";
list.add(string);

for (String s : list)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This program outputs:

```
123
456
```

which is pretty natural.

However, I'm thinking in another way. "string" is the reference(pointer) to the actual String object. When executing add(), it just stores the reference. When "string" refers to another String object, why the list still keeps the original one? Does it make a copy before add()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "value" of a String variable is a reference to the (immutable) object that is the string.

So there is no copy of the String but a copy of the reference. Having this reference doesn't allow you to change the original variable (you have no link to it) and doesn't allow you to change the string as it is immutable.

What you have here, inside the array contained by the arrayList after the two calls to add, is two different references. They could point to the same string but changing one reference doesn't change the other one. If you wanted to change the first reference in this case to point to the same string as the second one, the simplest would have been to do `list.set(0, list.get(1));`

Comment: Thanks. Copy of reference. Therefore after the first add(), there are two references pointing to "123", which are "string" and the first element of "list". Right?

Comment: Yes. The point to understand is that the value of an object of type variable is a reference to the object. You copy this reference when you pass it to a method, you don't pass a reference to the variable.

Comment: @htyleo: *"Therefore after the first add(), there are two references pointing to "123"..."* Right. (Actually, there are three, because you used a string literal to initialize `string`, and so there's a reference to it from the [`intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) pool as well [all string literals are interned automatically].)

Answer (score 2):

> When "string" refers to another String object, why the list still keeps the original one?

What you've added to the list is the reference to the string. Later, when you do

```
string = "456";
```

you're not *changing* the existing string, you're assigning a reference to a *different* string to the `string` variable. The original string is unchanged (in fact, strings in Java are immutable).

Answer (score 0):

because the variable 'string' is nothing but a pointer to a address in the memory. when you add 'string' in list the memory address of the 'string' is entered in the list. when you again assign a value , it justs change the address in the memory where the new variable is pointing